# Save image in picturebox with vb6

Tags: vb6, picturebox

i used vb6. i want to modify a picture in picturebox1 and process make that picture in picturebox2. so i want to save picture in .picturebox2. can you help me? i found this code but it didnt work

```
Private Sub save_Click()  
picturebox2.Picture = bitmap  
picturebox2.Picture = ("c:\\image\\image1.jpg")  
End sub
```

End Sub

Comment: Why you use a double backslash in your code: ("c:\\image\\image1.jpg") ? This, in VB6.0 is totally wrong.

Comment: thanks @GiorgioBrausi :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `SavePicture` statement.  This will probably save your graphic as a bmp file, not as a jpg file as your code snippet suggests.

```
SavePicture picturebox2.picture, "filename.bmp"
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445827(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: wheres the specific location file will be uploaded?

Comment: The file will be saved according to the path/filename specified on the SavePicture statement.  With just the filename ("filename.bmp"), it'll be saved to the current app folder, or you can specify a relative path ("..\folder\filename.bmp") or absolute path ("c:\tmp\filename.bmp").

Comment: its still error and notif like "run time error '380': invalid property value" and when i choose debug the codes is turning yellow "SavePicture picturebox2.Picture, "C:\Users\admin\Documents\VB\image1.bmp" "

Comment: Do you have a valid image in the control? Does that path exist? Do you have rights to access and create files on that path?

Comment: i dont know what i have to do, cause that still error till right now

Comment: One thing that will cause the `380 invalid property value` exception on the `SavePicture` statement is if there is not a valid image in the control.  Do you have a valid image loaded in the picture control?

Answer (score -1):

In VB6.0 you can convert BMP to JPG using additional code.

See my **BMP2JPG** sample project in my web site:

http://nuke.vbcorner.net/Projects/VB60/VB60variousprojects/tabid/79/language/en-US/Default.aspx#bmp2jpg

HTH

Comment: That link only seems to contain screenshots. If I click the "BMP to JPG " link in the leftnav it brings up an error page.  If you can copy here the relevant code from your example that would make this answer much more useful and also protect the information over time.