# In VB6, How do I take a Byte Array to BMP Image File?

Tags: arrays, vb6, byte, bmp

I already have taken/stolen - lol code from here to take a Byte Array of data and create a DIB in memory and using the StretchBlt function to fill in the picture of a picture box on a form.

I can not figure out, yet, how to create an actual file from the picture data.

A little backgound:  This array comes from an industrial UT instrument when given the serial command to dump a screen image.  The screen image comes over the serial port as a series of three digit decimal numbers.  There is a total of 38,400 Numbers in the byte array, which would be correct for a 640x480 display panel (640 * 480 = 307,200/8bits=38,400).  When that data is put though a SetPixels routine, it creates 307,200 points of data in a pixels variable. Pixels goes through a CreateDIB function to create a DIB.  That DIB is then sent through a DrawDIB to draw the screen shot in to a piucture box.  That works, but I had a hell of time adjusting the sizing to fit, but now it works fine.  I can get a great screen shot image from the instruments LCD panel!!!

How do I go to the next step and write it to an actual file?

Also, of interest with the picture box.  I can NOT copy the picture box image to the clipboard with:

```
Clipboard.Clear
Clipboard.SetData Me.PictureLCD.Picture, vbCFBitmap
```

I do not know why?  If I fill the picture in from a file instead with:

```
Me.Picture1.Picture = LoadPicture(FilePathName & Ext)
```

the picture copies to the clipboard with that same command no problem.  It's like the picture box shows the picture but it's not set.

I wouldn't necessarily  need to create the actual bitmap file if I could just get the picture box picture to the clip board.

I apologize if this is confusing and very grateful for help.

BTW, here is all the code, I was talking about above (stolen from an old article on here, modified for a 640*480 image)

```
        Private Const BI_RGB = 0&
        Private Const CBM_INIT = &H4
        Private Const DIB_RGB_COLORS = 0
        Private Const SRCCOPY = &HCC0020

        Private Type BITMAPINFOHEADER
            biSize As Long
            biWidth As Long
            biHeight As Long
            biPlanes As Integer
            biBitCount As Integer
            biCompression As Long
            biSizeImage As Long
            biXPelsPerMeter As Long
            biYPelsPerMeter As Long
            biClrUsed As Long
            biClrImportant As Long
        End Type
        Private Type RGBQUAD
            rgbBlue As Byte
            rgbGreen As Byte
            rgbRed As Byte
            rgbReserved As Byte
        End Type
        Private Type BITMAPINFO_256
            bmiHeader As BITMAPINFOHEADER
            bmiColors(0 To 255) As RGBQUAD
        End Type

        Private Declare Function CreateCompatibleDC Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
        Private Declare Function CreateDIBitmap Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, lpInfoHeader As BITMAPINFOHEADER, ByVal dwUsage As Long, lpInitBits As Any, lpInitInfo As BITMAPINFO_256, ByVal wUsage As Long) As Long
        Private Declare Function DeleteDC Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
        Private Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
        Private Declare Function SelectObject Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
        'Private Declare Function StretchBlt Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long, ByVal hSrcDC As Long, ByVal xSrc As Long, ByVal ySrc As Long, ByVal nSrcWidth As Long, ByVal nSrcHeight As Long, ByVal dwRop As Long) As Long
        Private Declare Function StretchBlt Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, _
                                                   ByVal x As Long, _
                                                   ByVal y As Long, _
                                                   ByVal nWidth As Long, _
                                                   ByVal nHeight As Long, _
                                                   ByVal hSrcDC As Long, _
                                                   ByVal xSrc As Long, _
                                                   ByVal ySrc As Long, _
                                                   ByVal nSrcWidth As Long, _
                                                   ByVal nSrcHeight As Long, _
                                                   ByVal dwRop As Long) _
                                                   As Long

        Dim Pixels() As Byte          ' Pixel data.
        Dim bm_info As BITMAPINFO_256 ' DIB bitmap info.
        Dim hDIB As Long              ' Bitmap handle.
        Dim wid As Integer            ' Size of the bitmap.
        Dim hgt As Integer

    Public Sub UpdatePictureBox(buff() As Byte)
    'Dim Buff(1023) As Byte

    ' fill the byte array ...
            
            Me.PictureLCD.Cls
            
            SetColorTable
            SetPixels buff
            CreateDIB
            DrawDIB
            'Me.PictureLCD.Refresh
            'Main.Picture2.Refresh

    End Sub


    Private Sub CreateDIB()
    Dim screen_hdc As Long

        With bm_info.bmiHeader
            .biSize = Len(bm_info.bmiHeader)
            .biWidth = wid          ' Width in pixels.
            .biHeight = hgt         ' Height in pixels.
            .biPlanes = 1           ' 1 color plane.
            .biBitCount = 8         ' 8 bits per pixel.
            .biCompression = BI_RGB ' No compression.
            .biSizeImage = 0        ' Unneeded with no compression.
            .biXPelsPerMeter = 0    ' Unneeded.
            .biYPelsPerMeter = 0    ' Unneeded.
            .biClrUsed = 256        ' # colors in color table that are used by the image. 0 means all.
            .biClrImportant = 256   ' # important colors. 0 means all.
        End With

        ' Get the screen's device context.
        screen_hdc = GetDC(0)

        ' Create the DIB.
        hDIB = CreateDIBitmap(screen_hdc, _
            bm_info.bmiHeader, CBM_INIT, Pixels(0, 0), _
            bm_info, DIB_RGB_COLORS)
    End Sub


    ' Draw the DIB onto the form.

    Private Sub DrawDIB()
    Dim compat_dc As Long
        
        
        
        ' Create a compatible device context.
        compat_dc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc)

        ' Select the DIB into the compatible DC.
        SelectObject compat_dc, hDIB

        ' Copy the compatible DC's image onto the form.
        'StretchBlt PictureLCD.hdc, 0, PictureLCD.ScaleHeight, PictureLCD.ScaleWidth, PictureLCD.ScaleHeight * -1, compat_dc, 0, 0, wid, hgt, SRCCOPY
        StretchBlt PictureLCD.hdc, 0, PictureLCD.ScaleHeight, PictureLCD.ScaleWidth, PictureLCD.ScaleHeight * -1, compat_dc, 0, 0, wid * 15, hgt * 15, SRCCOPY
        StretchBlt Me.Picture2.hdc, 0, PictureLCD.ScaleHeight, PictureLCD.ScaleWidth, PictureLCD.ScaleHeight * -1, compat_dc, 0, 0, wid * 15, hgt * 15, SRCCOPY
        ' Destroy the compatible DC.
        DeleteDC compat_dc
    End Sub


    ' Initialize 256 shades of blue.

    Private Sub SetColorTable()
    Dim i As Integer

        For i = 0 To 255
            bm_info.bmiColors(i).rgbRed = i
            bm_info.bmiColors(i).rgbGreen = i
            bm_info.bmiColors(i).rgbBlue = i
            bm_info.bmiColors(i).rgbReserved = 0
        Next i
    End Sub

    ' Create a drawing.
    Private Sub SetPixels(buff() As Byte)
        Dim Loops As Long
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim y As Integer
        Dim counter As Long
        counter = 0
        Dim tempCounter As Long
        tempCounter = 0

'        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

        'wid = 128
        'hgt = 64
        
        wid = 640
        hgt = 480
        
        ReDim Pixels(0 To wid - 1, 0 To hgt - 1)
        For y = 0 To hgt - 1

            Dim byteBits As String
            For x = 0 To wid - 1
                If tempCounter = 0 Then

                    byteBits = ByteToBit(buff(counter))

                    If (CByte(Mid(byteBits, tempCounter + 1, 1)) = 1) Then
                        Pixels(x, y) = 0
                    Else
                        Pixels(x, y) = 255
                    End If
                    Loops = Loops + 1
                    tempCounter = tempCounter + 1
                Else

                    If tempCounter = 7 Then
                        If (CByte(Mid(byteBits, tempCounter + 1, 1)) = 1) Then
                            Pixels(x, y) = 0
                        Else
                            Pixels(x, y) = 255
                        End If
                        Loops = Loops + 1
                        tempCounter = 0
                        counter = counter + 1
                    Else
                        If (CByte(Mid(byteBits, tempCounter + 1, 1)) = 1) Then
                            Pixels(x, y) = 0
                        Else
                            Pixels(x, y) = 255
                        End If
                        Loops = Loops + 1
                        tempCounter = tempCounter + 1
                    End If

                End If

            Next
        Next
        TextAdd CStr(Loops) & " pixels plotted)"    ' Here it reports 307,200, which is correct for an 640x480 display
ErrorHandler:
        Dim str As String
        str = Err.Description
        Dim a As Single
        a = 0
        
        Exit Sub
        
    End Sub

    Private Function ByteToBit(myByte As Byte) As String

    'Bit  ==  32103210
    '         --------
    '&HF0 == "11110000"
    '&H0A == "00001010"

        Dim k As Integer
        Dim x As Integer

        Dim valofbyte As Integer
        Dim mybytetobit As String

        valofbyte = val(CStr(myByte))
        mybytetobit = ""

        For k = 0 To 7
            x = 2 ^ k
            If valofbyte And x Then
                mybytetobit = "1" & mybytetobit
            Else
                mybytetobit = "0" & mybytetobit
            End If

        Next k

        ByteToBit = mybytetobit

    End Function

    Private Sub Picture1_Paint()
    'Picture1 is the PIctureBox
        DrawDIB
    End Sub
```

Well, I think I described all that in the message body.  I am stumped on why I can not put the picturebox image to the clipboard.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45163165/save-image-in-picturebox-with-vb6

Comment: "lol code from here" -- from where?

Comment: @JohnEason  Thank you!!!   It's that simple - lol.  I literally have no hair left, but after about a 16 hour session, I have what I need working now.  I'm not really sure how to use these forums, but I want to thank youy.

Comment: @StayOnTarget  Oh, my, I would have to find it again, but it was pretty much identical to what I published above.  I just changed the Width and Hight parameters.  You see the original ones commented out in the code.  There are issues setting the drawn image in the picturebox.    You must do this:

Comment: @StayOnTarget   Me.PictureLCD.Picture = Me.PictureLCD.Image, and if it is the very first time you run the program, up must repeat:

Comment: @StayOnTarget DrawDIB  and Me.PictureLCD.Picture = Me.PictureLCD.Image

Comment: @JohnEason  P.S.: New here.  Is there a better reply method.  This is very limited and not a full reply window like other forums.  Can add code, file or what not.

Comment: There's an editor below this thread ("Your Answer") where you can edit and post your answer, but you shouldn't use it for simple comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save image in picturebox with vb6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45163165/save-image-in-picturebox-with-vb6)